# I am using Azure Server, C# for Backend and PHP for front-end. I am getting Curl error: Failed to convert in some API's

Tags: c#, azure

[message] => Curl error: Failed to convert myappp-aman.azurewebsites.net​ to ACE; could not convert string to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I'm super confused as to how you are using PHP on the front-end, but since it's a string conversion failure providing the string would be useful if you can grab it from a break point or stack trace.